# Is there any way to use the tr command in place?

Tags: sed, gawk, tr

I want to remove all non-english alphanumerals from a file.

```sh
tr -sc '[:alnum:][:punct:]' ' ' <file
```

`gawk` and `sed` have the `-i` flag but I cannot find anything similar in the `tr` man pages.

How can I do this inplace, that is, store the output in the input file itself?

Comment: Note that as you're converting all newline characters to SPC, the output will end up being non-text.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How can I avoid that?

Comment: You could use [`sponge(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html).

Answer (score 7):

No. Very few commands have this functionality, GNU awk (`gawk`) only added it recently, and even for those commands that have an `-i` or equivalent, all it does is create a temp file in the background.

So, the way to do this is:

```bsh
tr -sc '[:alnum:][:punct:]' ' ' <file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

You could whip up a little function if you need this often:

```bsh
tri(){
  tmpFile=$(mktemp)
  echo "$@"
  case $# in
    ## You've given tr options
    4)
      trOpts="$1"
      set1="$2"
      set2="$3"
      inputFile="$4"
      ;;
    ## No options, only set1 and set2 and the input file
    3)
      set1="$1"
      set2="$2"
      inputFile="$3"
     ;;
    ## Something wrong
    *)
      echo "Whaaaa?"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  tr "$trOpts" "$set1" "$set2" < "$inputFile" > "$tmpFile" &&
    mv "$tmpFile" "$inputFile"
}
```

You'd then run this as:

```bsh
tri -sc '[:alnum:][:punct:]' ' ' file
```

Note how, unlike the real `tr`, this expects the file name as an argument and not as redirected input (`<file`), and that options be specified together as shown above (and not like `-s -c`).

Answer (score 2):

As that `tr` command always writes at most as much data as it reads, it should be safe for it to write its output in place:

With the `ksh93` shell:

```sh
tr -sc '\n[:alnum:][:punct:]' '[ *]' < file 1<>; file
```

(here converted to standard/POSIX syntax `[ *]` and adding newline to the list of characters to be preserved to avoid creating non-text output).

The `1<>;` ksh93-specific operator is like the standard `1<>` read+write-without-truncation one except that upon successful completion of the command being redirected, the file is truncated at the current position.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with the ksh93 shell. Will `tr -sc '\n[:alnum:][:punct:]' '[ *]' < file` work on bash?